# Injecting parcelables with Roboguice and Robotium

Tags: java, android, robotium, roboguice

I'm having problems while doing tests with Robotium, passing parcelables and injecting them with Roboguice.

As I've read on other places, I'd have to do this to pass intent extras

```
@Override
protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    Instrumentation instrumentation = getInstrumentation();
    Intent intent = new Intent(instrumentation.getTargetContext(), ConfirmOfferActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(PARCELABLE_OFFER, MockOffer.create());
    setActivityIntent(intent);
}
```

Now, when I try to run the tests I get this exception on the ConfirmOffer Fragment

```
    Reason: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't find the mandatory extra identified by key [com.parcelable.offer] on field class com.activity.offers.confirm.ConfirmOfferFragment.mOffer
```

Anyone?